# Why the data can't be pushed into the array when using promise of angularjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

the controllor:

```
var activeArr = [];
var activeDate = [];
var day = (endDate - startDate) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
for (var i = 1; i < day + 1; i++) {
    activeDate.push(endDate - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) * i);

    var start = endDate - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) * i;
    var end = endDate - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) * (i - 1);

    statisService.getRegStatis(start, end).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data.data); //can get data
        activeArr.push(response.data.data)
    });
}
console.log(activeArr); //nothing in the array
console.log(activeDate); // can push data into this array
```

the service:

```
userServiceModule.factory('statisService', ['$http','serverUrl', function($http,serverUrl){
    return {
        getRegStatis: function(startDate,endDate){
            var url = serverUrl +"/adminDA/dbReport?startTime="+startDate+"&endTime="+endDate;
            return $http.get(url);
        }
    };
}])
```

I can get the data from the service method,after this I want to push the data into an array,but there is nothing in the array,is this caused by the promise?
this is the console:
[image]

Comment: Your `console.log(activeArr);` needs to be in your callback, please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are logging the array before the promise has been resolved, update your code to log the array value inside your `.then` `callback` after you have updated the `activeArr` array

```
var activeArr = [];
var activeDate = [];
var day = (endDate - startDate) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
for (var i = 1; i < day + 1; i++) {
    activeDate.push(endDate - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) * i);

    var start = endDate - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) * i;
    var end = endDate - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) * (i - 1);

    statisService.getRegStatis(start, end).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data.data); //can get data
        activeArr.push(response.data.data)
        console.log(activeArr); //now your array will be populated
});
}

console.log(activeDate); // can push data into this array
```

Answer (score 3):

First change your factory:

```
userServiceModule.factory('statisService', ['$http','serverUrl', function($http,serverUrl){
        return {
            getRegStatis: function(startDate,endDate){
                var url = serverUrl +"/adminDA/dbReport?startTime="+startDate+"&endTime="+endDate;
                return $http.get(url).then(function(result){
                      return result.data;
              });
            }
        };
    }])
```

Then in the controller:

```
var activeArr = [];
var activeDate = [];
var day = (endDate - startDate) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
for (var i = 1; i < day + 1; i++) {
    activeDate.push(endDate - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) * i);

    var start = endDate - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) * i;
    var end = endDate - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) * (i - 1);

    statisService.getRegStatis(start, end).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data); //can get data
        activeArr.push(data);
        console.log(activeArr); //only now you can log activeArr because you have to wait for promise
    });
}

console.log(activeDate);
```

$http indeed returns a promise, but you need to return it from your factory function using .then or .success

Comment: thanks,but I want to do something else after the for circle end,so I log the data out of the for circle,how to do this?

Comment: @ParkerSong Your for loop will not wait for all the service calls to be completed. What do you want to do after the for loop?

Comment: You can declare your activeArr as $scope variable: $scope.activeArr=[]; $scope.activeArr.push(data);   after that this variable will automatically keep itself updated in DOM if you are using that variable as ng-model in your HTML.

Comment: @Tomislav deeply sorry,I can't accept two answer at the same time,and thank you very much,you helped me a lot.

Comment: @Parker, most important thing is that you have solved your problem. That is why SO is such awesome place

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt In the view,`ng-repeat="item in active track by $index"`,I want to put the two array into the `active` then can show in the view

Comment: @Tomislav,Yes,SO is a very nice place,and thanks again for your help

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt,I opened another question[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874626/how-to-deal-the-data-when-the-promise-in-a-loop]

Answer (score 1):

an $http will return you a promise - not the data. you should apply a callback after the $http call

```
$http.get('address').success(function(res) {
 //var res is the data sent back from the request..
// in your case it should look like
return res;
});
```